# How to conditionally concatenate based on YES/NO value in another cell in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, concatenation

| Text string | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 | Variables |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| An example of a string of text Var_1 Var_3 | YES | NO | YES | Var_1, Var_3 |

I currently have Var_1 to Var_N column searching "Text string" column for a specific word. Then I would like to have a column "Variables" that concatenates all the variable names with ", " where the value of the variable existing in the text string is TRUE. Would that be possibly?

Thank you kindly!

I am currently using Excel 2016 and would like to avoid VBA

Comment: what version of Excel?

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner I'm using Excel 2016

Comment: Then you will need to string them together with IF statements.  The dup has a few examples.